# Outlook appointment meeting organizer information inconsistent

Tags: vsto, outlook-addin

I am working on a VSTO add-in for Outlook, written in C# as a WFP application, and am running into an inconsistency in the Outlook provided data for the current selected appointment.

My add-in executes from a button in the appointment dialog. Here are the primary declarations I use to access information from the dialog:

```
Outlook.Application app = Globals.MyAddInApp.Application;
Outlook.AppointmentItem appt =
    app.ActiveInspector().CurrentItem as Outlook.AppointmentItem;
```

If I open an existing meeting and look at information in `appt`, the `appt.Organizer` gives me the name of the meeting organizer as expected. However, if I examine `appt.Recipients`:

```
string organizer;

foreach (Outlook.Recipient attendee in appt.Recipients)
{
    switch ((Outlook.OlMeetingRecipientType)attendee.Type)
    {
         case Outlook.OlMeetingRecipientType.olOrganizer:
             organizer = attendee.Name;
             break;
         case Outlook.OlMeetingRecipientType.olRequired:
             // ...
             break;
         case Outlook.OlMeetingRecipientType.olOptional:
             // ...
             break;
         case Outlook.OlMeetingRecipientType.olResource:
             // ...
             break;
     }
}
```

I'm finding that the meeting organizer has a type of `olRequired` not type `olOrganizer`. The `organizer` string in the above code is not set to the name of the organizer. The appointment dialog "Scheduling Assistant" clearly indicates the organizer, so I'm confused as to how the `Type` is showing up as `olRequired` and not `olOrganizer`.

It would seem odd to me that I can't just use the `Type` field to determine the roll of an attendee. Do I really have to check the `Organizer` attribute against the names in the `Recipients` to detect the organizer in the `Recipients` list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recipient type `olOrganizer` (0) is not used at all. You can only have To / CC / BCC recipients (mapped to `olRequired` / `olOptional` / `olResource` for appointments).

On the MAPI level, the organizer is marked by the `recipOrganizer` bit (2) in the `PR_RECIPIENT_FLAGS` set on the recipient. You can see that property in [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author) - select the appointment, click IMessage button, go to the GetRecipientTable tab, select the organizer, select the `PR_RECIPIENT_FLAGS` property, right click, "View Property".

Comment: Is there a way to access the "MAPI level" via C#?

Comment: Sure, you can read that property from the recipient using `Recipient.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x5FFD0003")`

Comment: Thanks! I've done a lot of searching and reading today after you posted your answer, and I have not encountered that possibility.

Comment: I guess I could also use `AppointmentItem.GetOrganizer()` to get the recipient object for the organizer. Bottom line is, you answered my question. I can't just walk through the `Recipients` list and know *all* of the roles without referencing a source outside of that list.

Comment: Organizer is a just a name, and hence it is not unique. OOM returns PR_SENT_REPRESENTING_NAME for that property. It is not however used when Outlook needs to figure out where the responses etc need to go - it uses recipOrganizer bit in the PR_RECIPIENT_FLAGS property for that.

Answer (score 0):

I've also faced this issue and was investigating.
This looks definitely like a bug in Outlook to me. I have opened a uservoice (for this one and another). Let's see if Microsoft will fix it.
https://outlook.uservoice.com/forums/322590-outlook-for-windows-desktop-application/suggestions/42151741-outlook-vba-wrong-recipient-type-for-organizer-olm

Comment: It is not a bug. Organizer is also a required attendee.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko it is a bug in the sense of it does not fit to the documentation

Comment: Let's say there is a zero chance of MS fixing it - olOrganizer (=0) recipient type was used only back in the MS MAPI days in mid-1990s. It has not been used ever since. There is no way they will invest the resources in fixing something that is not broken and risk breaking countless other customers who have been relying on the current behavior for decades.Especially since the workaround for you is so trivial.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko at least MS could update the documentation to reflect this.This is what mislead me as a vba developer.